# Чтение информации в текстовом файле в архиве c#

Tags: c#, zip, rar, txt

Нужно прочитать информацию в .txt файле в архиве формата .rar, .zip.

Comment: Ну не трольте, мне в переменную текст запихнуть надо, а для этого надо считать данные с текстового документа. :(

Comment: Посмотрите библиотеки для работы с архивами, их достаточно, SharpCompress например. В последних версиях .NET вроде что-то встроенное даже было.

Comment: Извините, сами что нибудь сделали?

Comment: Сделал распаковку, всё, понял, как сделаю, спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно попробовать так.

Это **тестовый вариант**, его нужно допиливать.

```
class ReadTxtInZip
{
    string _zipPath = @"D:\1.zip"; // путь до архива
    string _pathTxt = @"D:\"; // куда будет грузить файл из архива
    string _nameFile = "1.txt"; // текстовый документ его имя
    string _word = "Test"; // переменная которую записываем 

    public void workWithZip()
    {
        using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.Open(_zipPath, ZipArchiveMode.Update)) // открываем архив в режиме Update(Запись/Чтение)
        {
            archive.ExtractToDirectory(_pathTxt); // выгружаем файл из архива
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(_pathTxt+_nameFile, false, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)) // открываем файл
            {
                sw.WriteLine(_word); // записываем переменную
            }
            archive.CreateEntryFromFile(_pathTxt + _nameFile, _nameFile); // загружаем файл обратно в архив
        }

    }

    public void workWithZip2()
    {
        try
        {
            using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.Open(_zipPath, ZipArchiveMode.Update)) // открываем архив в режиме Update(Запись/Чтение)
            {
                archive.ExtractToDirectory(_pathTxt); // выгружаем файл из архива
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(_pathTxt + _nameFile, false, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)) // открываем файл
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(_word); // записываем переменную
                }
                archive.CreateEntryFromFile(_pathTxt + _nameFile, _nameFile); // загружаем файл обратно в архив
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Произошла ошибка: "+ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Устраните ошибку и нажмите кнопку, что бы продолжить!");
            Console.ReadKey();
            workWithZip2();
        }
        
    }

}
```

Код на гите: [тык](https://github.com/jlovenpk1/ForTraining/blob/master/ForTraining/StackOverflow/ReadFileZipTxt/ReadTxtInZip.cs)

Comment: `Close()` можно не вызывать, так как `StreamWriter` обёрнут в `using`. В любом случае закроется.

Comment: `Encoding.Default` - лучше никогда не использовать дефолтную кодировку. На каждом компьютере она своя. И файл, записанный на одном компьютере с дефолтной кодировкой, не откроется на другом. Следует всегда задавать конкретную кодировку, например, UTF8.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov всегда любил Сообщество СО, подскажут и укажут.
Тут, я как описал все в "тестовом" варианте.
Защиты от дураков нет.
Максимум перехват исключений.
По всем пунктам согласен, эт по привычки написал Close() :)

Comment: А потом ваши вредные привычки будут скопированы кучей новичков. Код лучше поправить.

Comment: @aepot ok-ok, did.